# Tridion Category XmlName with Content Porter

Tags: content-porter-2013, keyword

Using the Content Porter API we're building on the idea of the [DTAP-it extension from Jaime and Warner](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.de/2015/06/dtap-it.html)

One issue we have is the XmlName of the Category is different from Dev and ACC, and this is causing problems.

I recall in the past we would sometimes manually hack the Content Porter XML export definitions and change the Publication name, for example, to re-arrange the blueprint.

Would it be reasonable to do the same thing here, hacking the CP export XML and changing the Category XML name to be the same as the destination server?

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a `mappings.xml` file to transform the `XmlName` during the import, rather than hacking the Content Porter export.

According the online documentation, the mappings file allows you to:

> handle items that were renamed on the source system or on the
>   destination system after a transfer

...Which seems to fit your scenario.

Within the XML file, your transform/rename should be in the following format:

```
<tcccp:Mapping exportContext="[Publication]" exportTitle="[Source Category Title]" importContext="[Publication]" importTitle="[Destination Category Title]" />
```

This is described in more detail in [Changing mappings](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-FC185DB5-14E9-4CA4-9BC3-CC00F7E43E14) section of the online documentation.